# OpenCV 4.4.0 build errors with Yocto

Tags: opencv, yocto

I am trying to include OpenCV 4.4.0 in my Yocto build using the opencv_4.4.0.bb recipe I found at http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-support/opencv
My Yocto version is 2.2.0 (Morty).

I don't see any issues when building opencv_3.4.3. However, I am running into errors when building 4.4.0 with bitbake:
`bitbake opencv`.
Here's a part of the error log:

```
/media/phyvm/dubuk/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-phytec-linux-gnueabi/opencv/4.4.0-r0/contrib/modules/intensity_transform/src/bimef.cpp: In function 'cv::Mat cv::intensity_transform::solveLinearEquation(const cv::Mat_<float>&, cv::Mat_<float>&, cv::Mat_<float>&, float)':
/media/phyvm/dubuk/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-phytec-linux-gnueabi/opencv/4.4.0-r0/contrib/modules/intensity_transform/src/bimef.cpp:136:10: error: 'Index' is not a member of 'Eigen'
     for (Eigen::Index i = 0; i < tempx.rows(); i++)
          ^~~~~
/media/phyvm/dubuk/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-phytec-linux-gnueabi/opencv/4.4.0-r0/contrib/modules/intensity_transform/src/bimef.cpp:136:30: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
     for (Eigen::Index i = 0; i < tempx.rows(); i++)
                              ^
/media/phyvm/dubuk/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-phytec-linux-gnueabi/opencv/4.4.0-r0/contrib/modules/intensity_transform/src/bimef.cpp:145:10: error: 'Index' is not a member of 'Eigen'
     for (Eigen::Index j = 0; j < tempy.cols(); j++)
          ^~~~~
/media/phyvm/dubuk/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-phytec-linux-gnueabi/opencv/4.4.0-r0/contrib/modules/intensity_transform/src/bimef.cpp:145:30: error: 'j' was not declared in this scope
     for (Eigen::Index j = 0; j < tempy.cols(); j++)
                              ^
/media/phyvm/dubuk/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-phytec-linux-gnueabi/opencv/4.4.0-r0/contrib/modules/intensity_transform/src/bimef.cpp:158:10: error: 'Index' is not a member of 'Eigen'
     for (Eigen::Index j = 0; j < W_h.cols(); j++)
          ^~~~~
/media/phyvm/dubuk/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-phytec-linux-gnueabi/opencv/4.4.0-r0/contrib/modules/intensity_transform/src/bimef.cpp:158:30: error: 'j' was not declared in this scope
     for (Eigen::Index j = 0; j < W_h.cols(); j++)
                              ^
/media/phyvm/dubuk/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-phytec-linux-gnueabi/opencv/4.4.0-r0/contrib/modules/intensity_transform/src/bimef.cpp:160:14: error: 'Index' is not a member of 'Eigen'
         for (Eigen::Index i = 0; i < W_h.rows(); i++)
              ^~~~~
/media/phyvm/dubuk/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-phytec-linux-gnueabi/opencv/4.4.0-r0/contrib/modules/intensity_transform/src/bimef.cpp:160:34: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
         for (Eigen::Index i = 0; i < W_h.rows(); i++)
```

I've tried to search for these errors online but I can't find anything similar. It appears that a header file might be missing or not up to date, but I'm not sure. Has anyone had these issues with Opencv4?

Comment: As you can see on this website (http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/39865/) on the end of the page, the version you tried belongs to the current master.  I would advice to use the latest release (not the master) of yocto (Dunfell) and using it's opencv version (4.1.0).  Mixing old releases with new bitbate recipes isn't alwasy an easy task.

Comment: opencv_4.1.0 compiled with no issues. Thanks a lot!